# Jersey Jackson JSON attribute change globally

Tags: json, jackson, jersey-2.0

I have a scenario that if there is an XML attribute (defined as `@XmlAttribute`) in the POJO then it should named differently in the JSON output.

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "value")
//@JsonProperty("value-new")
protected String value;
```

Now I can use `@JsonProperty` to define the new name. But I have plenty of such attributes in each POJO and the name change required is "common" for all of them (say add -new) at the end. Is it possible to do this globally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own `PropertyNamingStrategy`.

```
class XmlAttributePropertyNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String nameForField(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedField field, String defaultName) {
        XmlAttribute annotation = field.getAnnotation(XmlAttribute.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            return defaultName + "-new";
        }
        return super.nameForField(config, field, defaultName);
    }
}
```

You can use it as below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY); // enable fields
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, Visibility.NONE); // disable getters
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new XmlAttributePropertyNamingStrategy());

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Pojo()));
```

Because `XmlAttribute` annotation is available on field level we need to enable fields visibility and disable getters. For below `POJO`:

```
class Pojo {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String attr = "Attr";
    private String value = "Value";
    // getters, setters
}
```

Above example prints:

```
{"attr-new":"Attr","value":"Value"}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had idea implement via JSonserialization but this looks simpler. Also one has to enable feature `MapperFeature.ALLOW_EXPLICIT_PROPERTY_RENAMING)` if field explicit naming to make it work.